# how to prevent losses after a hard or soft fork

Tags: transactions, blockchain-fork, confirmations, soft-fork

i learned about hard and soft forks from this [question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/30817/what-is-a-soft-fork); now i have a basic understanding about forks; but the answers of that question did not say what happens to transactions on the stale chain; if i understand correctly those transactions are simply given up? but this looks like people would lose their money if they received payments on the stale chain; how does the bitcoin protocol protect them in this case? (there is a timer for confirmation of transactions but i am still not sure how it is being used and why it is adequate;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what happens to transactions on the stale chain; if i understand correctly those transactions are simply given up?

Correct. In the case of a stale (abandoned) chain, any transactions that happened in the stale blocks (that did not also happen in the active chain's blocks) would no longer exist on the bitcoin network.

> but this looks like people would lose their money if they received payments on the stale chain; how does the bitcoin protocol protect them in this case?

Also correct. There is no built-in 'protection' against having a transaction included in a stale chain. As a user, it is almost always recommended that you **wait for a few confirmations before you consider a transaction as fully settled**. This helps ensure that your transaction isn't included in what will eventually become a stale chain. Often, people quote **six blocks** as being a high level of assurance.

In practice, we can see that it is exceedingly rare for there to be a stale fork that runs longer than just a couple of blocks. See [this question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3343/what-is-the-longest-blockchain-fork-that-has-been-orphaned-to-date) for some examples of past forks.

Comment: thank you and i highlighted the main points;