# I made a payment of bitcoin into escrow for services that were not delivered and bitcoin not returned

Tags: fraud, escrow

I made a payment of bitcoin into escrow for services that were not delivered. I requested that the funds be returned and they have been removed from escrow, but never returned to me. Can I do anything to recover my funds?

Comment: How did you choose the escrow service?

Comment: Hi, it was an escrow service which was approved through the vendor, so I unfortunately went with it. Appreciate your response.

Answer (score 2):

You can contact the service provider, and the escrow agent to request a refund, but beyond that there is likely nothing that can be done. If you have lost a substantial amount of money, you could file reports with your local law enforcement agency, but understand that there is almost no chance they will be able to help you recover the funds.

Bitcoin transactions are not reversible, once confirmed several blocks deep in the blockchain history, the chance of [that transaction being removed or replaced is basically zero](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3343/what-is-the-longest-blockchain-fork-that-has-been-orphaned-to-date). The only way those funds can be returned, is if the person who now controls them decides to send a transaction paying you back.

Sorry for your loss here, it is unfortunate to hear that even after employing an escrow agent, your trade did not go as planned.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and thoughts. It was my first involvement with bitcoin and a learning experience. If it comes back I’ll look at that as a bonus, as currently the vendor and escrow contacts are both ignoring any contact.

Comment: @Alrob01 I see in your other comment that the escrow was approved by the vendor, so that makes me wonder if the two were colluding (or perhaps, were the same person). If you employ an escrow agent, its best to find one yourself, that the vendor then also agrees with. In any case, I hope your funds are recovered!