# Orphan blocks explorer

Tags: chain-reorganization, blockchain-explorer, stale-block

Is there any blockchain explorer that lists orphaned blocks or reorgs?

How often does it happen in general? I only found this site which doesn't show any orphaned blocks after 2017: https://www.blockchain.com/charts/n-orphaned-blocks

Im trying to download all blocks into a database and want to verify I have correct blocks

Comment: Related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/97192/5406