# Bitcoin re-org stats

Tags: chain-reorganization, stale-block

Does anyone have a table of historic Bitcoin reorgs?

Something like

- [yyyymmdd] [blockheight] 1 stale block
- [yyyymmdd] [blockheight] 1  stale block
- [yyyymmdd] [blockheight] 2 stale blocks
- [yyyymmdd] [blockheight] 1 stale block
- ...

I can't generate this myself unless I have a full node running since genesis, correct?

Thanks!

Comment: Not an answer, but an obvious complication of such data is that it depends on the observer. Not every node will see every reorganization, by definition (if everyone saw the same thing, there'd never be a reorganization). It depends on their network distance to the miners who created the relevant blocks.

Comment: Does anyone have some sort of idea at least? How often to single, double and maybe triple stale blocks happen?

Comment: You can find some of this data here: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/4638/5406. For more recent infos you can check out the RSS feed of BitMEX Research's forkmonitor: https://forkmonitor.info/feeds/stale_candidates/btc.rss

Comment: You may also be interested in https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/97197/5406